# Results of DecodeBase64 only 1 Byte on Android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

```
procedure Foo;
    var str:String;byteArray:TBytes;
    begin
      str :=  'test';
      str :=  EncodeBase64(@Str[1],sizeof(Char)*length(str));
      byteArray:= DecodeBase64(str);
      showmessage(string(byteArray));
    end;
```

Running on Windows gives me "test" as message. On Android I only get the "est", "est2" or blackscreen and crash. Debugging under Android shows me that byteArray stores only the first Byte.
Am I doing anything wrong or is this a known issue?

EncodeBase64 is from Soap.EncdDecd.pas of the RAD-Studio XE7 source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 encodes binary to text. And decoding decodes text to binary. So, starting with a string you need to encode the text to binary using some well defined text encoding. For instance:

```
var
  bytes: TBytes;
....
bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

Now you can base64 encode `bytes` which is binary as required.

In the reverse direction, decoding the base64 encoded text yields a byte array representing UTF-8 encoded text. Decode that like so:

```
str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

In XE7 you should not use `Soap.EncdDecd`. Instead use [`System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding). Call `TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString` to encode as base64 and `TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes` to decode.

To encode:

```
bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
base64 := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(bytes);
```

To decode:

```
bytes := TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(base64);
str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

The key message is the base64 encodes binary to text. That is often misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks. Precise and helpful answer as always. Have a nice day.